# PhoneGap, Local-Storage paging solution

Tags: cordova, webkit, local-storage

**Local-Storage**, 
how to paging it?

IE:

first page fetch 1-5 items, 
second page fetch 6-10 items.
 
3td page, list 11--15 items...

any SQL example? thanks
SELECT * FROM USER WHERE AGE < 10 LIMIT 10; May I use "TOP 10" here?

Detail API:
http://docs.phonegap.com/en/1.8.0/cordova_storage_storage.md.html#Storage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For first page you can use:

```
var value0 = window.localStorage.getItem("key0");
var value1 = window.localStorage.getItem("key1");
var value2 = window.localStorage.getItem("key2");
var value3 = window.localStorage.getItem("key3");
var value4 = window.localStorage.getItem("key4");
```

Similarly for other page.
I hope it will work.